# How to fix Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, backend

I'm building a JavaScript, HTML and CSS forum project for school. I'm currently trying to figure out how to connect firebase database to my project. I think I've figured it out, but when I try to run my html document with live server, I get this error: `Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"`. See code below:

HTML snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            //Code
        </head>

        <body>
            //Code
            <script src="form.js" type="module"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript (note: data to firebase code not done yet):

```
import { initializeApp } from "/node_modules/firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "/node_modules/firebase/database";

// Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //Configuration here
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
const db = getDatabase(app);

const formDB = ref(db, "submit_form")

// Form Code
document.getElementById("submit_form").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);


function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var titleVal = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var reviewVal = document.getElementById("review").value;

    console.log("Title: " + titleVal, "| " + "Review: " + reviewVal);

    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#title, #review');

    inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.value = '';
    });
}
```

As said, when running my html file which will create a post to this forum-site, which is connected to the form.js file, i get the `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`. I'm using firebase V9 SDK without any bundles, just vanilla JS and Node.JS. If there's any question, please answer to this post. Thanks in regard!

Comment: Try typing the URL of the script into the address bar of a new browser tab. Quite possibly it will be an HTML file sent by the server describing an error of some kind.

Comment: Your stated JavaScript code looks like a node.js script that runs server side. What is the code of your "form.js" that runs in the browser? If it is a static file the webserver will add the proper mime type, if delivered by your node.js app you might need to specify the mime type.

Comment: @traktor tried that, I just get a black and white screen with the code of the file on it. Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @PeterThoeny Form.js is just vanilla javascript. I use VS Code extention "Live Server" to run the HTML files, i havent yet connected the pages to an actual server.

Comment: JavaScript module script MIME type must be `text/javascript` but the server responded with `text/html`. One common reason for this is typo in file path causing server to return 404 page. Less likely reason is Live Server setting MIME types incorrectly.